# Check for multiple values in a M2M relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

In English, I want to check whether a user's type is either a viewer, a moderator, or an administrator.

Here is the relevant part of my `models.py`

```
class UserType( models.Model ) :
    name = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )

    # id |       name
    #----+------------------
    #  1 | tenant
    #  2 | property manager
    #  3 | property owner
    #  4 | vendor manager
    #  5 | vendor
    #  6 | viewer
    #  7 | moderator
    #  8 | administrator

class UserProfile( models.Model ) :
    user       = models.OneToOneField( User )
    user_types = models.ManyToManyField( UserType, null = True, blank = True )
```

By the way, I set `user.profile` to be the same thing as `user.get_profile()`.

In my `views.py` code, I want to do the checking. I figured out that

```
[ user_type.pk for user_type in user.profile.user_types.all() ]
```

will give me a list of `pk`'s for the `user`'s `user_type`, like so `[ 1, 2, 6 ]`. Meaning that this particular user is a tenant (1), property manager (2), and a viewer (6).

If I just want to check one `user_type`, then I can simply do

```
if 6 in [ user_type.pk for user_type in user.profile.user_types.all() ] :
    # This user is a viewer
```

But how can I check multiple user_types/pks? I wanted to do something like

```
# This won't work
if [ 6, 7, 8 ] in [ user_type.pk for user_type in user.profile.user_types.all() ] :
    # This user is either a viewer, moderator, or administrator
```

Also is my method of list comprehension to check `user_types` the **Django-way**? It doesn't seem like it, but I couldn't figure out how to query it *cleanly* in Django.

Any tips and suggestions welcomed. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I just figured out I can list pks the more Django-way with [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

```
user_types = user.profile.user_types.values_list( 'pk', flat = True )
# [ 1, 2, 6 ]
```

I also figured out that I *could* check multiple values like this

```
if len( set( [ 1, 9 ] ).intersection( set( user_types ) ) )
    # True because of 1 is in user_types (don't care about 9)

if len( set( [ 4, 99 ] ).intersection( set( user_types ) ) )
    # False because 4 nor 99 is in user_types
```

But even this `set` method doesn't seem very Django-friendly. There must be an easier way right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do:

```
def has_roles(user, roles):
    return user.profile.user_types.filter(pk__in=roles).count() == len(roles)

print has_roles(user, [6,7,8])
```

P.S. I would shy away from using hard coded PK ID numbers as your identifiers. Too many things can go wrong with that. Instead define a mapping at runtime and reference them by names. Multiple things will improve:

- Your code will be much easier to read
- Django will offload model instance matching to the DB the first item
- From then on you can cache the ID and not ask the DB again

Then you can do:

```
class UserType( models.Model ):
    TYPES = (( 'tenant', 'Tenant'),
             ( 'propman', 'Property Manager'),
             ( 'propown', 'Property Owner'),
             ( 'vendman', 'Vendor Manager'),
             ( 'vendor', 'Vendor'),
             ( 'viewer', 'Viewer'),
             ( 'moderator', 'Moderator'),
             ( 'admin', 'Administrator'))

    name = models.CharField( max_length = 135, choices=TYPES )

def has_role(user, role):
    return user.profile.user_types.filter(name=role).count() == 1

def has_roles(user, roles):
    return user.profile.user_types.filter(name__in=roles).count() == len(roles)

print has_roles(user, ['viewer','moderator','admin'])
```

Finally, you can add the two functions above to:

```
class UserProfile( models.Model ) :
    user       = models.OneToOneField( User )
    user_types = models.ManyToManyField( UserType, null = True, blank = True )


    def has_role(self, role):
        return self.user_types.filter(name=role).count() == 1

    def has_roles(self, roles):
        return self.user_types.filter(name__in=roles).count() == len(roles)
```

And then use it like this in the future:

```
u = User.objects.get(username='me')
if u.userprofile.has_role('admin'):
    print 'I have the powah!'
```

Comment: Awesome train of thought! I definitely agree that your method is much cleaner and simpler. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One comment: I'm not sure if I follow your `has_roles` function. Why are you setting it to `== len( roles )`? Doesn't that logic means, for example, the `user` has been `viewer`, `moderator`, *AND* `admin` (as oppose to the desired *OR* logic)?

Comment: Nevermind, I decided to use your function `has_roles()` for everything and left out `== len( roles )`. Now it works just the way I want. Thanks again!

Comment: It's simply an optimization for the DB. If you do .count() DB only has to count the number of rows, it doesn't have to fetch the names of the roles and python doesn't have to construct the `UserType` objects. The difference is indeed OR vs AND. Without `.count() == len(roles)` its equivalent to OR logic (user has any of those roles), with len(roles) its equivalent to user has ALL of those roles. Cheers